# hadoop2.4.0 namenode -format showing NoClassDefFoundError error

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, bigdata

I have configured and install the HADOOP
I configured from the website 
http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/38/build-install-configure-run-apache-hadoop-2.2.0-microsoft-windows-os 

when I format the hadoop namenode using the command 

 `alim@Hadoop~/hadoop-2.4.0/bin$ ./hdfs namenode -format  
or
  alim@Hadoop~/hadoop-2.4.0/bin$ ./hadoop namenode -format`

It is showing the "NoClassDefFoundError" exception 

The following is the exception shown when I ran the "hadoop namenode -format" command 
           `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/server/namenode/NameNode
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.  Program will exit.
Exception in thread "main"`


At first i thought the hadoop classpath is the not pointing to the Hadoop-core jar files but when I ran the command 
  `alim@Hadoop~/hadoop-2.4.0/bin$ ./hadoop classpath` 
 
It is showing the correct path to libraries then why the NoClassDefFoundError is getting
The path to libraries are showing like below:

        `/home/alim/hadoop-2.4.0/etc/hadoop:/home/alim/hadoop-2.4.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/:/home/alim/hadoop-2.4.0/share/hadoop/common/:/home/alim/hadoop-2.4.0/share/hadoop/hdfs:/home/alim/hadoop-2.4.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/:/home/alim/hadoop-2.4.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/:/home/alim/hadoop-2.4.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/:/home/alim/hadoop-2.4.0/share/hadoop/yarn/:/home/alim/hadoop-2.4.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/:/home/alim/hadoop-2.4.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/:C:\cygwin64\home\alim\hadoop-2.4.0/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar`

please help I am beginner to Hadoop.... Any ideas